# Simple query to run on bigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am going to run a very simple query using python script. To make sure my script is working I am going to create a very simple .sql file with a simple query **which does not depend on any other table**.

something like: select currentDate
or something similar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need a `from` clause in BigQuery.  So something like this:

```
 select 1 as x
```

or:

```
 select current_date as curdate
```

I would suggest that you give the column a name so you can verify that you can access the column in your code.